# Problema com Seed Relacionamento entre Categoria e Sub-Categoria no Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel-4, laravel

Nao sei como eu faço com minha Seeds, tenho 2 entidades: Categoria e Sub-categoria.
Quero poder rodar as *seeds* e poder cadastrar minhas Categorias
e após minhas Sub-categorias, só que Sub-categoria tem um relacionamento com Categoria: precisa do `id` da Categoria para o `insert`.

Além do `insert` também tem a questão do `delete` se caso dar um `RESET` na *seeds*:

```
relacionamento 1 > N
```

Answer (score 2):

Insira manualmente a sua chave primária nas suas categorias para assim poder criar o relacionamento das subcategorias.

Em relação ao reset da migration, você pode instruir seu Banco de dados a não realizar a checagem de chaves estrangeiras. Em MySQL ficaria assim:

```
public function run()
{
    // Desabilita a checagem de chaves
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;');
    DB::table('categorias')->delete();

    // Suas migrações
    User::create(array(
         'id' => 1,
         'categoria' => 'teste1'
    ));      

    // Habilita novamente checagem de chaves *Importante*   
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

E por que não criar apenas uma entidade?

Migration:

```
    Schema::create('categories', function($table)
    {

        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('parent_id')->nullable();

        $table->string('name');

        $table->boolean('inactive')->default(0);

        $table->timestamps();

        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';

    });
```

Relacionamentos:

```
/**
 * Define an inverse one-to-one or many relationship.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'parent_id');
}

/**
 * Define a one-to-many relationship.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Category', 'parent_id');
}
```

Para criar e atribuir:

```
    $parent = new Category;
    $parent->name = 'Parent';
    $parent->save();

    $child = new Category(['name' = 'Child']);

    $parent->children()->save($child);
```

Fica mais simples!